# Groovy - Shorter way to write an unix grep like closure

Tags: groovy, closures

I have a closure to find all files with name matching a pattern and containing a given String:

```
def path = "path/to/logs"
def namePatten = ~/.*.log/
def contentPattern ~/.*ERROR.*/
def result = []

new File(path).eachDirRecurse { File dir ->
  dir.eachFileMatch(namePattern) { File f ->    
    f.eachLine { String l ->      
      if(l.matches(contentPattern)) {        
        result.add(f)
        return
      }
    }
  }
```

But I'm pretty sure I can have something shorter (hey, else I can use plain java :) )
I have tried to find a way to write this a bit like that:

`result = new File(path).eachFileRecurse.filter(filePattern).grep(contentPattern)`

as I would have done using guava or similar fluent interface collection tools.

How woud you write this closure in a concise, yet still readable, manner ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest I can get it to at present is to use the [`File.traverse` method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#traverse%28java.util.Map,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29) to recursively scan the root folder:

```
new File( path ).traverse( nameFilter: namePattern ) { f ->
  if( f.filterLine( { it ==~ contentPattern } ) as String ) result << f
}
```

Using [`filterLine`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#filterLine%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) returns a [Writable](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Writable.html) which I convert to a String as then we can exploit the Groovy truth to see whether to add the file to `result` or not.

---

#### Edit:

You can also use `AntBuilder` to do a similar thing:

```
def result = new AntBuilder().fileset( dir:'path/to/logs', includes:'**/*.log' ) {
  containsregexp expression:'.*ERROR.*'
}*.file
```

Which I tend to prefer as it generates the list in one go, rather than adding results to an already defined `results` list.

Comment: I like the ant builder option. I'm still waiting a bit for some alternative groovy code that others might submit.